# Python 3 - Spinning text

Tags: regex, python-3.x, spintax

I'm stucked on doing something like this..

**from this**

```
{Hi|Hello} I am - {Me|You|Us}
```

**to this**

```
#Possible results
'Hi I am - You'
'Hello I am - Me'
'Hi I am - Us'
'Hello I am - You'
```

So basically, the code will search for words **which are enclosed in curly braces {}**. Those curly braces have multiple words inside them which would be splitted. All in all, every curly braces will output only word, which it will choose randomly.

Do I need regex for this? I tried searching for premade libraries, but I just found an outdated one..can anyone help please?

Comment: You don't explain what you are trying to do in any comprehensible way.

Comment: Is "Hello I am - Us" and "Hi I am - Me" possible?

Comment: Sorry guys, I just updated my question..sorry for the unclear one..I'm just really frustrated from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is relatively simple -- the only occurrences of `{` and `}` are for the purposes of providing multiple possible text fragments as shown in the question -- you could use a regex like the following:

```
import re

p = re.compile('(\{[^\}]+\}|[^\{\}]*)')
```

Then you'd split the text into fragments like so:

```
frags = p.split("{Foo|Bar} baz {quux|wibble}.")
# ['', '{Foo|Bar}', '', ' baz ', '', '{quux|wibble}', '', '.', '']
```

For each string in this list, you can generate a list of possible values (only one for the strings not starting with `{`):

```
def options(s):
    if len(s) > 0 and s[0] == '{':
        return [opt for opt in s[1:-1].split('|')]
    return [s]

options("foo")
# ["foo"]

options("{foo|bar}")
# ["foo", "bar"]
```

Then build a list of lists of options:

```
opt_lists = [options(frag) for frag in frags]
```

Then build the Cartesian product and join:

```
import itertools

for spec in itertools.product(*opt_lists):
    print(''.join(spec))
```

Here's the output for the `"{Foo|Bar} baz {quux|wibble}."` example:

```
Foo baz quux.
Foo baz wibble.
Bar baz quux.
Bar baz wibble.
```

If there are additional complexities in your inputs, you might need to use more complex regular expressions or a parser for the actual input format, but the general idea of producing a list of lists of options as an intermediate result remains valid.

Comment: Python 3 requires you to add `r` to your string to avoid re module identify some chars as unicode chars. ie, the compile should be like `p = re.compile('(\{[^\}]+\}|[^\{\}]*)')`. I'm wondering how to make this work with nested brackets.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Tintadgel:~ dhoelzer$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('(Hi|Hello) I am - (Me|You|Us)')
>>> print p.match("Hi I am - You")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106481470>
>>> p.match("Hi I am - Yo")
>>>
```

Here's what's happening.  We start by importing the Regular Expression library.  With that done we next compile a regular expression that looks for a string that begins with either "Hi" or "Hello" and ends with one of the following: Me, You and Us.

With that created we can now run matches against it directly.  Notice that `print p.match("Hi I am - You")` returns an object.  This means that we had a match!  Conversely, `p.match("Hi I am - Yo")` returns nothing, indicating that there was no match found.

Hope this helps!  You may want to take a peek at http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this isn't what I want to do. Understandable, because I wasn't clear on my question. Apologies!

Comment: What is it that you're looking to do, then?